# How to get value of upload file

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have an file input, for the user to upload a file. Once the file is selected, I want to log to the console the name of the file. For some reason, when I do console.log, it returns an empty string to the console.

```js
document.getElementById('file-upload').addEventListener('change', function() {
  console.log(this.value)
})
```

```html
<input type='file' id='file-upload'>
```

Comment: Works fine for me, in firefox I get `c:\fakepath\[filename]`. You can log `this.files[0].name` instead to get just the name.

Comment: It also works well for me in Chrome :-)

Answer (score 1):

To get uploaded file name you need to edit your js as follow:

```
document.getElementById('file-upload').addEventListener('change', function() {
   console.log(this.files.item(0).name)
})
```